# Cross reference between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables with the same structure and with records that are changed over time and that now I need to compare.
Tables are `T1` and `T2` and both have the columns:

```
Id,
Name,
Id2.
```

I have stored in `T1.Id2` the reference id of the matching records (by `Name`) of the second table.
So, for example, in T1 I have the following value:

```
id  name      id2
---------------------
1   mario     0   
2   vittorio  0
3   andrea    2
4   giuseppe  3
```

and need to have the following results in T2:

```
id  name      id2
--------------------
 1  riccardo   0
 2  andrea     3
 3  giuseppe   4
 5  giacomo    0
```

So, I need to store in the second table, the id of the first table for the same records. Where in `T1` there is `T1.Id2>0` i need to set in `T2.Id2` the corresponding `T1.id`
Any ideas for a query?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It isn't completely clear how you want to join these two tables, whether it is `T1.Id2` to `T2.id` or if it is `T1.Id2` to `T2.Id2`.

Comment: @gordon Linoff: In the first table I have Id2 that has the id's of the matching records of the second table. I need to have in the second table the same thing: the id of matching records of the first table. So, in the second table in column id2 i have to store the id of the first table. Every table keep their own Id, but have also a column id2 with the corresponding id on the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an update join:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.id2 = t2.id
SET t2.Id2 = t1.id
WHERE
    t1.Id2 > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this query in phpmyadmin has stuck the system (loading message stay forever). Maybe it lead to a loop, I don't know.

Comment: Before I speculate on your comment, have you paid any attention to the comments under your question asking you to clarify your question?

Comment: I have provided an example, so now it must be clear what I need.